# Java - How to use changing/modified variables in several methods in a class?

Tags: java, variables, instance-variables, local-variables

The idea of local variables is a little hard to understand when I want one method to initialize a variable and another method to use that initialized variable.

Example

```
public class abc

public int startAngle;

public void angleMethod(){
startAngle = 90;
angle = startAngle;
}

public void methodTwo(){
anotherVar = angle + 10;   //I want this angle to be initialized to 90
```

Is having angle already initialized to 90 by the first method possible? The reason I want this is so that I can break down the things I want to do to the variable into smaller individual methods.

I tried passing the variable as a argument in the second method, something like:

```
public void methodTwo(int angle)
```

but that didn't work.

I've read of using

```
 this.angle = angle
```

but im not sure what this does or its purpose. I believe that i do need to do things to variables and then use those modified variables in other parts of my program.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Please tell us more detail of just what you're trying to do and why as it seems confusing (at least to me). Please show us your real code too. When is the class constructed and what constructs it? When and who calls the two methods, and are they always called one after the other? Perhaps you're looking to use constant values? I really can't tell.

Comment: Nowhere in the 'code' you showed did you declare the variable `angle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not understanding what a local variable is.  In your example, `angle` in `angleMethod()` is different from `angle` in `methodTwo()` (as far as I can tell, based on the code provided, although I don't see where you're declaring angle).

I think something like this is what you are going for:

```
public class abc
{
    //Declare class-scoped variables, accessible by all class methods.  Could be public or private.
    public int startAngle;

    //constructor - initialize vars here
    public abc()
    {
        startAngle = 90;
    }

    public void method()
    {
        int angleVar = startAngle + 10; //startAngle will be 90.
        //angleVar will be 100;
        //angleVar can only be accessed inside this method.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses this is clearer now, I was being silly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initialize an attribute when the object is created, you have two options:

- Default value

  ```
  int startAngle = 90
  ```
- Assignation in (all of) the constructor(s)

Apart from that, if you want to check if other method has been invoked before the current method, you should program that yourself (by example, the method that has to be called first sets an attribute and the other one checks it).